# Techniques for scaling data matrix to avoid rank deficiency issues

Tags: least-squares, multicollinearity, linear-algebra

I have a $n \times p$ matrix $A$ where $n$ is the number of observables and $p$ is the number of observations. $n \gg p$

In my code, I have done $[E,V] \,=\, eig(A)$ and doing a least squares operation on the eigenvector matrix $V$, which is $p \times p$. This is using the `mldivide` operator in MATLAB, such that `X = V\b;`.

My data is fairly huge, and I am getting warnings from MATLAB that $V$ is rank deficient, and thus the condition number is too high to get a reasonable answer.

*Are there any standard techniques/tools out there to overcome this?* I have tried shifting and scaling $V$, and reading threads here on this topic, but no avail.

The `mldivide` works for smaller datasets, where $p \sim O(10^1)$. However, when I go to $O(10^2)$ and beyond, I face rank deficiency issues.
I would welcome suggestions.

A few useful points about my data (I can provide more details if required):

1. This data is coming from an experiment of an extremely chaotic physical phenomenon, and therefore is noisy.
2. The $V$ matrix consists of eigenvectors in complex conjugates, and there is a lot of variation in every eigenvector (order of magnitude ranges from $10^{-14}$ to $10^{-1})$.

Comment: Are you sure it's a numerical problem, not the real issue with rank deficiency?

Comment: I have solved that problem since its been a year. But I still have the same question for some of my datasets, especially econometric statistical data like weekly gas prices over a decade etc. I tried mean-subtraction, normalizing by 1, scaling etc. but the rank deficiency is unchanged. So I am looking for general pointers how to approach this.